# Visual Studio deploying old version

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm deploying an ASP.NET webapp with Visual Studio. When I do a local test, the changes aren't always saved-- it deploys an older version of some pages. When I try to deploy it to Azure or run it just in chrome the changes aren't  saving.

I've tried deleting temporary ASP.NET files from C:/Windows/etc. and deleting the old deployment data, but none of it works.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: And how is the title relevant to the question?

Comment: Whoa, that was a mistake. I started asking that question, figured it out, and forgot to change the title

Comment: Try CTRL-F5 in your browser for a forced refresh

Comment: Wow, Ctrl-F5 loaded the most recent version. Will the version be deployed too, or will that just update the most recent version on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem.
Your proxy server could be caching the data and serving you with an older version. Use a different network to access the website. If it shows the newer version, then you can conform that it is indeed the caching problem.

Comment: I don't think I have a proxy server-- I don't have a proxy extension or anything and I'm just deploying the site to Azure and I wouldn't think Azure has a proxy on it either. 

That said, it's definitely a cache problem but ctrl-f5 fixed it.